# In Compose Multiplatform, DropDownMenu is not available in commonMain?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-desktop, compose-multiplatform

Do I have to call it from specific platforms (in my case Android and desktop)?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not available. It's because it has different API on these platforms.

On [Android](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/f28daa8e82452d013f385c270549a91d62ff6339/compose/material/material/src/androidMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/AndroidMenu.android.kt#L75) it has `popupProperties` parameter, which contains a lot of Android specific parameters, .e.g `dismissOnBackPress` is meaningless on Desktop.

On [Desktop](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/f28daa8e82452d013f385c270549a91d62ff6339/compose/material/material/src/desktopMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/DesktopMenu.desktop.kt#L76) this parameter is replaced with only one of `popupProperties` properties - `focusable`.

You can create your own version using `expect`/`actual` and reuse platform specific version with the needed parameters